# integrate the diagram viewer of activiti in webApp

Tags: activiti

I am new to Activiti and have little experience.  My question is,  how can i integrate the diagram viewer of Activiti in web application to show diagram  as it's shown by Activiti Explorer?

Comment: I'm in the research phase, I did some research and I found the open source "activiti-crystalball" solution, but I'm always looking for the best one .

Comment: But as I understand from their website cyrstalball does *much* more than just displaying diagrams. Plus Activiti Explorer actually *is* a webapp. Why not have a look inside and copy the bits you need?

Comment: thanks, I will make a copy and scan the code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Rest API, it is relatively easy to retrieve the URL of the process diagram (assuming it was deployed as part of the .bar file).

The call sequence is:

Get the process deployment ID using something like: GET /activiti-rest/service/process-definitions

Alternatives you can get the Process definition from the TASK or PROCESS INSTANCE

Once you have the process you are interested in, get the details of the process: GET activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions/ where ID is the ID you selected from 1.

Get the resource details, this URL will be returned in the diagramResource field of the above call.

Finally, add the returned image url to your html page.

Hope this helps. Greg